# How to print non sequentially?

Tags: java, printing

What I'm trying to do is print a divider BELOW the line that will have a scanner collecting user input, and I want it displayed before the user submits said input. Pseudocode for desired outcome:

```
PRINT (DIVIDER)
SCANNER
PRINT (DIVIDER)
```

I want the two dividers displayed before the user hits enter (which is when the bottom div should print normally). Is this even possible?

Comment: So you want two dividers printed before the user hits enter, then you want the user's input to display between the two dividers?

Comment: You can't do this directly in Java, as single threaded apps ALWAYS execute sequentially, and even if you added non-sequential behavior through something like threading, only a single thread can manipulate the console at a time. That being said, you could print  the two lines, then clear the screen after the user enters something and reprint the lines with the user input in between them. Or you could do some ioctl magic and redraw the screen, which is how many programs work but it's certainly more complex.

Comment: Ah, a shame. Thanks for letting me know.